# Insert or replace into in combination with iterrows()- sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

I read a .txt file and end up with data like that:

```
    Date Ticker Tenor  Strike        IV
1   2017-02-03   MXEA    1M    50.0  34.96749
2   2017-02-03   MXEA    1M    60.0  34.36383 ...
```

Now I want to write the `dataframe` to a **sqlite3** table, but take duplicates under consideration. Hence I thought I try this approach:

```
    for index,row in df.iterrows():
   con.execute('INSERT OR REPLACE INTO ImpVol_Data (Date, Ticker, Tenor,Strike,IV) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)',[row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4]])
```

Unfortunately I receive a error message saying the following:

```
InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

I really want to understand my issue here. 
The types of the Columns are as following:

```
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
Name: Ticker, dtype: object
Name: IV, dtype: float64
```

So I have 1 date object, 2 objects and 2 floats. I also tried something like :

```
   ....',[row[0],str(row[1]),str(row[2]),row[3],row[4]])
```

To convert the objects to string to match the TEXT column in my table.

Comment: The sqlite adapter doesn't know how to convert `datetime64` objects. You'd have to convert those to something sqlite *does* handle. See [Converting between datetime, Timestamp and datetime64](//stackoverflow.com/q/13703720)

Comment: I don't know if sqlite supports python datetimes or not but if it does you can do `df['Date'].dt.to_pydatetime()` to convert it

Comment: thank you it worked, but one more question (as always ....)
why does it not replace my existing entries in the Table?
do i have a mistake in my query?

Comment: @StefanMüller If you have a new question, ask a new question. (Or read the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html).)